# How to group matching data from first two column

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I would like to group data from first two fields as per below

**Sample Data:**

```
CHECK|checkadm|block1
CHECK|checkadm|block2
CHECK|checkadm|block3
CHECK|checkadm|block4
TEST|testadm|block1
TEST|testadm|block2
TEST|testadm|block3
```

**Final Output**

```
CHECK|checkadm|block1|block2|block3|block4
TEST|testadm|block1|block2|block3
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried awk command but it didn't worked

Comment: [edit] your question to show what you tried and explain in what way it didn't work. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, using *array* concatenation on each rows:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=""}
    {a[$1"|"$2]=a[$1"|"$2]"|"$NF}
    END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}
' file
```

```
TEST|testadm|block1|block2|block3
CHECK|checkadm|block1|block2|block3|block4
```

Answer (score 0):

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) version 1.8 (assuming input is already sorted like the sample in the question):

```bash
$ datamash -t'|' --collapse-delimiter='|' -g1,2 collapse 3 <ip.txt
CHECK|checkadm|block1|block2|block3|block4
TEST|testadm|block1|block2|block3
```

You can use `datamash -t'|' -g1,2 collapse 3 <ip.txt | tr ',' '|'` with earlier versions if your input doesn't have the comma character.